# Difference between Proto runtime and compiler

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Sorry for stupid question, but I am new to protobuf and there are 2 concepts mentioned in the context of it. Protobuf compiler and protobuf runtime. What is the difference between these and what do these exactly do?

My understanding is that the public protobuf compiler is protoc, but there are probably other compilers out there too. It is a script that takes the .proto file and generates, say a .java class from it. Is that correct?

But what is Protobuf Runtime? If Compiler already generates the .java file, what do we need runtime for? Is it similiar to Java Runtime in the sense of being a runtime library of its own with its own classes (that generated .Java classes might reference)?

Comment: Think of the runtime as the core. protoc generates all of the stuff specific to *your application* and nothing more. The core is *everything else* that makes it all work. It's not specific to any application; it is generic. An analogy would be the JDK which contains String, ArrayList etc. It'd be like saying "why do I need the JDK? I already compiled all my classes with javac". Yes, but your classes are just a tiny fraction of what makes the whole application work. You also need all the core stuff.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. Does that mean the runtime is used during the compilation, meaning the compiler itself depends on the runtime or does the generated proto contain some dependencies that are resolveable by the runtime?

Comment: The runtime isn't used during compilation, no. The compiler is just creating source code, so its really just converting text from one form to another (proto to class files). Any dependencies the compiler has will just be to do with the text manipulation, if any. The generated classes may have some dependencies on the runtime though. That's kind of an implementation detail